# Process ten of thousands of merge commands [NEO4J]

Tags: neo4j

I'm relatively new to Neo4j and am seeking advice from more experienced users on how to improve the performance of inserting hierarchical data into my database.

I'm working on a project where I consume a stream of `items`, each represented by its path from root to leaf, along with a timestamp indicating when it was received. The data has a hierarchical structure, and I aim to represent this in a variety-tree-like structure within my Neo4j database.

For example, an `Item` might be represented as an array with a path and a timestamp, like so: `(Array(a,b,c,d), timestamp)`.

Here's an example of my current Cypher statement for inserting an item, where some fields are static (unchanging) and others are dynamic (unique to each item):

```
MERGE (a0:D0 {l: '<static>'})-[:N]->(a1:D1 {l: '<static>'})
MERGE (a1)-[:N]->(a2:D2 {l: '<dynamic>'})
MERGE (a2)-[:N]->(a3:D3 {l: '<static>'})
...
MERGE (a9)-[:N]->(a10:D10 {l: '<dynamic>'})
MERGE (a10)-[:N]->(a11:D11 {l: '<dynamic>'})
ON CREATE SET a11.v = [<timestamp>]
ON MATCH SET a11.v = a11.v + <timestamp>
```

This approach represents how I update or insert an item into the database.

However, when dealing with approximately 20,000 such statements, needing to be executed in a transaction, I encounter significant performance issues. I'm using the Neo4j Java driver, constructing a single large query and executing it in an `asyncSession`.

When executing these statements periodically throughout a minute, it takes about 20-30 seconds for the operations to complete. However, attempting to perform all insertions at once at the end of the minute results in the operation not completing at all.

I'm looking for any suggestions on how to optimize this process. Is there a more efficient way to structure my queries or manage transactions to handle this volume of data more effectively? I'm starting to feel a bit desperate for a solution.

Thank you in advance for any advice or insights you can provide!

Comment: 1. Do both "dynamic" and "static" values come from the input data (I think you call them "items"?), or do "dynamic" values come from the data in your DB? 2. Do you have indices on the `l` property for all the `Dn` node labels (e.g., `D0`, `D1`, ...)? 3. To be safe, your first `MERGE` should be broken down into 3 separate `MERGE`s.